# using helper methods in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, model

by helper methods I mean methods that help me, not methods in the helper files

I have a class method `User.make_from_file` and inside I have pretty ugly logic. I want to seperate it to methods but for some reason it doesn't work

```
class User

...

def self.make_from_file(filename)

some logic

User.new(read_attr_from_file(filename))

end

  private

  def read_attr_from_file(filename)
    some logic
  end

end
```

but I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attr_from_file' for #<Class:0x007fa4d4b4b290>
from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: The method defined is instance methods, and you are calling as class method.

Answer (score 3):

```
class User

   def self.make_from_file(filename)
      User.new(read_attr_from_file(filename))
   end

   private

   def self.read_attr_from_file(filename)
      ...
   end

end
```

Try this

Comment: The `private` keywords applies only to instance methods, so `User.read_attr_from_file` is public. To make it private, either use `private_class_method` or use `private` within `class << self`

Answer (score 1):

To further `jbmyid`'s answer, you will benefit from looking at the [**difference between instance & class methods**](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

> What you're doing is trying to populate a `new instance` of the class
>   using an `instance` method
>
> This won't work, as instance methods are designed
>   to load on a class which has already fired its`initialize` method. As your `read_attr_from_file` is not part of any predefined class, you'll need to make it a `class method`

---

**Update**

If you're trying to call a class method, it doesn't matter what the class is; you just have to do it without the class being initialized previously. I.E:

```
def self.read_attr_from_file filename
  ...
end

#-> User.read_attr_from_file filename
```

If you wanted to call a method on an already initialized class (an `instance` of a class), you'll be able to use:

```
def read_attr_from_file filename
end

# -> user = User.new
# -> user.read_attr_from_file
```

In terms of the answer, you have to remember that you're calling `User.new` (class method), but in order to populate the new object, you'll need to use another method, which will be run on a non-initialized object, hence it needs to be a class method:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.make_from_file filename
       User.new read_attr_from_file(filename)

       #-> User.new is class method
       #-> read_attr_from_file called on class, needs to be class method
   end

   private

   def self.read_attr_from_file filename
   end

end
```

Comment: read_attr_from_file is just another method defined in the user class. What is the problem if I try to access it within the class?

Comment: See my comment above regarding private class methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650286/using-helper-methods-in-model#comment36325072_23650401